# Rounding issue when finding integers inside the interval with float bounds

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I have a code which does the following. In some loop, it solves quadratic inequality (ax^2 + bx + c <= 0, a > 0) and finds integer numbers between the roots (using my own function `integer_inside`).

```
>>> np.roots([1, -9, 16])
array([6.56155281 2.43844719])
>>> integer_inside(np.roots([1, -9, 16]))
array([3,4,5,6])

>>> np.roots([1, -9, 18])
array([6. 3.])
>>> integer_inside(np.roots([1, -9, 18]))
array([3,4,5,6])

>>> np.roots([1, -9, 20])
array([5. 4.])
>>> integer_inside(np.roots([1, -9, 20]))   # It should return array([4,5])!
array([])
```

In the last case, though, `np.root([1, -9, 20])` formally returns `array([5., 4.])`, but `integer_inside` returns an empty array. And if you check:

```
>>> np.roots([1, -9, 20]) == np.array([5., 4.])
array([False, False])
```

This is due to the fact that under the hood `np.roots([1, -9, 20])` returns `array([4.000000000000001, 4.999999999999999])` and there are, of course, no integers inside...

The first idea is to use `np.round()`. But this would mean that I have to remember about it and put `np.round()` everywhere else in the code where the corresponding calculations take place. Next, it is also not obvious which precision to chose.

Is this issue unavoidable or is there any other general and pythonic solution?

Answer (score 0):

How about calling the numpy function as follows:

```
np.roots([1, -9, 18]).astype(int)

Out:
[6 3]
```

This way you ensure the output of the function is always in integer form. Unless you still want to have access to the float values, but that shouldn't be a problem since you can store the output of np.roots into a variable and apply ".astype(int)" whenever you need to.

```
val = np.roots([1, -9, 18])

print("val: ", val)

print("val_int: ", val.astype(int))

Out:
val:  [6. 3.]

val_int:  [6 3]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help much, since my goal is not to have integer output of `np.root()`, but to find integers inside this output. See the first example in my question.

Comment: @user7647857 , oh okay, my bad I understand now, I assumed the problem was with the output of the numpy function. In that case I would ask if you can provide the code for your `integer_inside` function